# Youtube-Js-Api / How can I include the request’s response in my actual webpage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, youtube-data-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm working on an app with both Firebase (web app) and the youtube API. The idea is to let users share their playlists and interact.

1) First, the user must identify himself. This part works very well (firebase part)

2) Then, the user must accept some conditions (the scopes) from the youtube API.

3) The Youtube API return the result of the request.

The issue is that youtube API recreate for every item of the array the HTML structure : HTML > HEAD > BODY. Plus, the response skips my header and display the all thing in a blank page instead of reacting like an include PHP (i know this is javascript but still.. ).

I know the solution rest in the function executerequest but i can't figurate how to do it.

The code of the request is in the middle of the body but for the purpose of my post, i did separate it.

```js
 var GoogleAuth;
    var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl';
    function handleClientLoad() {
        // Load the API's client and auth2 modules.
        // Call the initClient function after the modules load.
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
    }

    function initClient() {
        // Retrieve the discovery document for version 3 of YouTube Data API.
        // In practice, your app can retrieve one or more discovery documents.
        var discoveryUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest';

        // Initialize the gapi.client object, which app uses to make API requests.
        // Get API key and client ID from API Console.
        // 'scope' field specifies space-delimited list of access scopes.
        gapi.client.init({
            'apiKey': '...',
            'discoveryDocs': [discoveryUrl],
            'clientId': '....',
            'scope': SCOPE
        }).then(function () {
            GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

            // Listen for sign-in state changes.
            GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

            // Handle initial sign-in state. (Determine if user is already signed in.)
            var user = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
            setSigninStatus();

            // Call handleAuthClick function when user clicks on
            //      "Sign In/Authorize" button.
            $('#sign-in-or-out-button').click(function() {
                handleAuthClick();
            });
            $('#revoke-access-button').click(function() {
                revokeAccess();
            });
        });
    }

    function handleAuthClick() {
        if (GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get()) {
            // User is authorized and has clicked 'Sign out' button.
            $('#sign-in-or-out-button').html('Sign out');
            $('#revoke-access-button').css('display', 'inline-block');
            GoogleAuth.signOut();
        } else {
            // User is not signed in. Start Google auth flow.
            GoogleAuth.signIn();
        }
    }

    function revokeAccess() {
        GoogleAuth.disconnect();
    }

    function setSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        var user = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
        var isAuthorized = user.hasGrantedScopes(SCOPE);
        if (isAuthorized) {
            $('#sign-in-or-out-button').html('Sign out');
            $('#revoke-access-button').css('display', 'inline-block');
            $('#auth-status').html('Connecté ' +
                ' Granted');

            defineRequest();

            console.log('connecté');

        } else {
            $('#roomRed').html('display', 'block');
            $('#sign-in-or-out-button').html('Sign In/Authorize');
            $('#revoke-access-button').css('display', 'none');
            $('#auth-status').html('Déconnecté' +
                ' Denied');
            console.log('déconnecté');
        }
        // This helper method displays a message on the page.

    }

    function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        setSigninStatus();
    }


    function createResource(properties) {
        var resource = {};
        var normalizedProps = properties;
        for (var p in properties) {
            var value = properties[p];
            if (p && p.substr(-2, 2) == '[]') {
                var adjustedName = p.replace('[]', '');
                if (value) {
                    normalizedProps[adjustedName] = value.split(',');
                }
                delete normalizedProps[p];
            }
        }
        for (var p in normalizedProps) {
            // Leave properties that don't have values out of inserted resource.
            if (normalizedProps.hasOwnProperty(p) && normalizedProps[p]) {
                var propArray = p.split('.');
                var ref = resource;
                for (var pa = 0; pa < propArray.length; pa++) {
                    var key = propArray[pa];
                    if (pa == propArray.length - 1) {
                        ref[key] = normalizedProps[p];
                    } else {
                        ref = ref[key] = ref[key] || {};
                    }
                }
            };
        }
        return resource;
    }

    function removeEmptyParams(params) {
        for (var p in params) {
            if (!params[p] || params[p] == 'undefined') {
                delete params[p];
            }
        }
        return params;
    }



    function executeRequest(request) {
        request.execute(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            for(var i = 0; i< response.items.length; i++){
            console.log(response.items[i].player.embedHtml);
                document.write(response.items[i].player.embedHtml);

            }
        });
    }

    function buildApiRequest(requestMethod, path, params, properties) {
        params = removeEmptyParams(params);
        var request;
        if (properties) {
            var resource = createResource(properties);
            request = gapi.client.request({
                'body': resource,
                'method': requestMethod,
                'path': path,
                'params': params
            });
        } else {
            request = gapi.client.request({
                'method': requestMethod,
                'path': path,
                'params': params
            });
        }

        executeRequest(request);
    }

    /***** END BOILERPLATE CODE *****/


    function defineRequest() {
        // See full sample for buildApiRequest() code, which is not
// specific to a particular youtube or youtube method.




        buildApiRequest('GET',
            '/youtube/v3/playlists',
            {
                'mine': 'true',
                'maxResults': '25',
                'part': 'snippet,contentDetails,player',
                'onBehalfOfContentOwner': '',
                'onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel': ''


            });

/*
        buildApiRequest('GET',
            '/youtube/v3/playlistItems',
            {
                'playlistId': "PLsvlo6Soc2pc2ZlereiehdPRhm0eKjSxI",
                'maxResults': '25',
                'part': 'snippet,contentDetails'
            });
*/
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mes vidéo </title>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
 
<button id="sign-in-or-out-button"
        style="margin-left: 25px">Sign In/Authorize</button>
<button id="revoke-access-button"
        style="display: none; margin-left: 25px">Revoke access</button>

<div id="auth-status" style="display: inline; padding-left: 25px"></div><hr>


<div id="video-container"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
        onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
        onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you by advance